# How do I give the first paragraph of a section a rule?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GY30.png)

Hello! My Name is PK and I struggle to understand to understand English sometimes..

I believe I can use a ">" to show the parent or something, but I'm not sure..

I did try to use google/w3/mozilla docs , but I didn't know what to search in.
I thought it was parents or first of, but... I was unable to succeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are CSS selectors https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

There's is one specifically that allows you to target the first child of a tag.

Hence with that in mind you can do the following to target the first paragraph of each sections:

```
section p:first-of-type {
    text-indent:20px;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the css selectors on w3 schools. i felt hella stupid with everyone downvoting me but ill definitely bookmark this.

cheers

Comment: Cheers mate, don't worry about the votes. Keep learning and asking question, this is the way for growth.

Answer (score 1):

For first paragraph in section you can use css [:first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) pseudo class. To be sure it is inside the `section` you should put:

```
section p:first-of-type {
    text-indent: 20px;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. i was super discouraged seeing all the downvotes and felt stupid but you kindness helped a lot.